# spring tool suite Plugin execution not covered error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

i created a spring mvc project.but eclipse sts shows an error.this error shows for every project i create.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teGHS.png)

error shows in this tag of `pom.xml`

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

here is the error.[see image for clarify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is6FH.png)

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin 

org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies
 could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: 
ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval 
of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to 
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Network is unreachable: connect
```

i'm new to both sts and maven.i'm not sure is this relevent to sts or maven.i tried some `so` similler question but those are related to different thing .however this error is still coming.can you help me to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to put the plugin label between build label like this:

```
<build>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</build>
```

if you put it so and the problem continue, then apparently it is a connection problem. Make sure you have internet connection or if you are behind a proxy, configure setting.xml  in m2 directory like this:

```
<proxies>
     <proxy> 
        <active>true</active>
         <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>user</username> 
        <password>password</password> 
        <host>200.55.156.179(for example)</host> 
        <port>3128(for example)</port> 
        </proxy>

</proxies>
```